# How to bind i at the end of a sequence using Seq.iteri

Tags: f#, sequence, loops

```
mySequence
|> Seq.iteri (fun i x -> ...)
...
```

How do I bind i at the end of the sequence?  In other words how do I bind the value representing the number of iterations iterated by iteri?

Of course I could create a ref and assign i for all iterations, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **fold**, so that

```
Seq.iteri (fun i x -> ...)
```

becomes

```
Seq.fold (fun i x -> ... ; i+1) 0
```

along these lines:

```
let aSeq = 
    seq {
        for i in 1..10 do
            printfn "eval %d" i
            yield i
    }

let r = 
    aSeq 
    |> Seq.fold (fun i x ->
        printfn "iter %d" x // or whatever is "..."
        i+1) 0     

printfn "result: %d" r
```

Comment: For me Folds are one of the functional idioms that has really changed the way I approach problem solving.  You should spend some time with them if you can Moonlight.

Comment: Thank you gradbot, I appreciate the encouragement!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you could just use function that will directly return length of the sequence that is passed to Seq.iteri (since Seq.iteri will iterate over the whole sequence). This will be more functional programming way instead of thinking about mutable variables:

```
Seq.length mySequence
```

In your case:

```
mySequence |> Seq.iteri (fun i x -> ...)
let i = Seq.length mySequence
```